# A part of my model goes transparent when I click the Toggle X Ray Button

Tags: modeling, transparency

I’m making a model for a game, and I’m not sure what happened, but when I click on the “Toggle X-Ray button, one half of the neck is transparent. I click on the neck and the one section I’m talking about has two halves that are combined into one piece, like I wanted it to be, but one half of it goes completely transparent. Does anyone know what could have happened, and how to fix it?

Comment: We'd need to see an image of it, but first thought is do you have a mirror modifier on it?

Comment: Check your normals too.